# Does Bullet type matter? (excluding shotguns)

Tags: battlefield-4

When looking at gun stats, it displays their bullet type. For example, some sniper rifles shoot .338 while others shoot .308. Does this affect the performance of the gun at all?

I know shotgun shell types present very clear differences, but for other guns it seems it may be much more subtle as in just things like velocity or drop.

Comment: Damage wise it does not seem to affect anything. It may affect bullet drop.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it may play into the bullet drop, accuracy, firing rates, and be there simply for aesthetics. I found a couple useful links that may shed more light on the subject.

[Battlelog BF4 Forum](http://battlelog.battlefield.com/bf4/forum/threadview/2955065221060019259/)

[Synthic BF4 Stats](http://symthic.com/bf4-stats)